# value binding in KnockoutJs fails for select when having complex types

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use the value binding on the select element, as described in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeEast/nM6dd/2/

However, I cannot seem to be able to set the selected option (value binding).

I know I can use the optionsValue binding, but that makes the value a string instead of an object which is not preferable. If that is the only way to go, how would I do to ensure that the selected option is written back to the view model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the solution. You have to add the attribute `optionsValue: 'id'` to the data-bind.
You also have to put a function in you viewModel that returns the selected object.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, name: "Apple" }, 
    { id: 2, name: "Orange"},
    { id: 3, name: "Banana"}
  ]);
  this.selectedItemId = ko.observable(3);
  this.selectedItem = function() {
    var self = this;
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.items(), function(item) {
      return self.selectedItemId() == item.id;
    });
  }.bind(this);
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/1.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedItemId"></select>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem().name"></span>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It does solve the question I asked. However, my problem is rooted by another cause than this. I am loading the array from the server asynchronously and when I get the response I set the value of the observableArray. This means that the observableArray reloads/rebinds which in turn makes it ignore the *value* previously set.
That might be by design, but I'm not sure. Here is a fiddle showing the behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeEast/nM6dd/12/

Comment: I see. The problem is that this.selected is an observable and it is set to 2. By design knockout can change the value on this.selected when you change the value on the list. Because the list it empty at first this.selected becomes undefined. When you fill it it by default sets to first item. You can solve this by saving the current selected item in an own variable and by using the function subscribe  in knockout.