# Manually set default values for a select box using knockout on complex objects

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js

I am trying to update the selected value in one of the select boxes using knockout. But I am not able to do so. Here is the jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/5MauG/1/

When I click on the click me span, I expect that the selected value in the select box should change.

Comment: I foud the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610874/value-binding-in-knockoutjs-fails-for-select-when-having-complex-types?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that trying to set the selected option to a new object won't work. Even with the same values, the new object is not the same as the old object. You can see that in this slightly [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/5MauG/2/); it works when actually choosing from the objects in the options array.

With an array of values, like strings or ints, you can select by value. With an array of objects, you need to select with the actual object. This will be easier if your view is using the bindings everywhere, because the bindings *will* represent the actual objects.

Comment: I ran into this myself this morning.  Your answer did the trick.  Thanks!