# Knockout: How can I set the value of a select box whose options are javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a `select` element that is bound to a list of complex javascript objects using the `options` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'countryName', value: selectedCountry, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

where availableCountries is an observable array of javascript objects. You can see the full example [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7csj5/1/).

Now, this works fine when I select an item in the list. However, if I need to update the value from some other part of the application, I will only be able to do so if I use the exact same Country object as lies in the availableCountries array. This has also been established in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638609/manually-set-default-values-for-a-select-box-using-knockout-on-complex-objects), but unfortunately it does not solve my problems.

In the documentation of the [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), they anticipate this problem, and say that I should use the `optionsValue` binding:

> Typically you’d only want to use optionsValue as a way of ensuring
>   that KO can correctly retain selection when you update the set of
>   available options. For example, if you’re repeatedly getting a list of
>   “car” objects via Ajax calls and want to ensure that the selected car
>   is preserved, you might need to set optionsValue to "carId" or
>   whatever unique identifier each “car” object has, otherwise KO won’t
>   necessarily know which of the previous “car” objects corresponds to
>   which of the new ones.

But this unfortunately will not work, as it also affects the value binding - if I set `optionsValue` to `'countryName'`, `selectedCountry` will only contain the name of the country and not the entire object.

I'm looking for a way to combine these. I still want value to be the entire object, but I want the option value comparison to use a specific property that I specify. Basically, something in the lines of:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'countryName', optionsComparator: 'countryName', value: selectedCountry, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

However, as far as I can see, this involves modifying the `value` binding. Do I have any other options? Can I solve this in some other way? Extenders? A custom binding handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a selected binding that fixes this problem, check my collection of bindings

Demo, the dropdown is at the end of the page
http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/8/

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

Code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selected = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var selected = valueAccessor();
        var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().options);
        var key = allBindingsAccessor().optionsKey ? allBindingsAccessor().optionsKey : allBindingsAccessor().optionsText;

        var observable = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(selected);
                return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function (item) {
                    return value != null ? ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[key]) == ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value[key]) : false;
                });
            },
            write: function (value) {
                writeValueToProperty(selected, allBindingsAccessor, "selected", value);
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: observable });
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this should work for me. Clever! I played around with it a bit, and made some modifications. One is to allow options to mutate. Another is to allow optionsKey to be a function, in case you want to do more complex comparisons (like how optionsValue can be a function). I also added disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved to the computed. http://jsfiddle.net/7csj5/3/

Comment: Glad you liked it, about the computed, it should be garbage collected by the JS engine if the binding is removed

Comment: I added your changes to Github

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by attaching a getCountryByPop method to my availableCountries array, then calling it to set the observable's value:

```
availableCountries.getCountryByPop = function(pop) {
    var ret;
    this().forEach(function(country) {
        if (country.countryPopulation == pop) {
            ret = country;
        }
    });
    return ret;
};

...

viewModel.selectedCountry(availableCountries.getCountryByPop(9));
```

[jsfiddle.net/6BaP5/](http://jsfiddle.net/6BaP5/)